# Ubuntu 12.04 lts cannot build a wireless connection

Tags: wireless

Hi i just got a new notebook and it came with ubuntu 12.04 lts operation system. But it can't make a wireless connection. I plugged in my Ethernet cable and i can reach the Internet with it but I need wireless connection so much. This is the first time I'm using ubuntu so i'm really confused. I can see wireless networks (including mine) but i cannot use them. It seems like it's establishing a connection but soon it gives up.

Here is the output of the wireless script: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6279692/

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: I can't enter the site pastebin.com what else can I do?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6279692/

Answer (score 0):

Please enable this in your router:

> disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP

Then copy and paste one line at a time:

```
echo "options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800pci
sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci
```

Comment: OK, how can i enable that? I literally do not know what that means...

Comment: Do you know how to get into your routers configuration? or do you own the router?

Comment: Do you mean the ADSL modem?

Comment: If it is also your router, you just log into it then find the drop down menu that says WWw/QoS and enable it. But go ahead and run the other commands first and see if that helps.

Comment: I performed the commands before and after enabling the "QoS" and i still cannot connect wifi. And now i cannot see any wireless networks, or anything called "wireless". The wireless option of the notebook is disappeared.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and start the computer with recovery and return to factory settings. It is worse now.

Comment: Post the contents of `sudo /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf` so we can see if the if the changes were saved.

Comment: No need we can correct it.